# Перенос строк Notepad++

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Строки имеют вид:

> grimaldiimonkaspia
> :KAsZHDqxGJ
> grissingertahsin
> :IUHVC7K03h
> grissingertahsint
> :NCTrDiVvHu

Требуется привести к результату:

> grimaldiimonkaspia:KAsZHDqxGJ
> grissingertahsin:IUHVC7K03h
> grissingertahsint:NCTrDiVvHu

Answer (score 2):

Найти:

```
\s+:
```

Заменить на:

```
:
```

- Зациклить поиск

Режим поиска:

- Регулярные выражения

<kbd>Заменить все</kbd>

Comment: Я искал ответ 2 дня, спасибо огромнейшее!!!!